# How can I prevent the input volume from changing?

Tags: microphone

My input volume bar seems to change somehow. How can I lock my input volume and make it fixed?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype has an option to allow or forbid automatically changing the input level; it does this to even out changes in user voice volume and avoid clipping or undermodulation (call quality in general is or used to be the biggest thrust at Skype).  The Skype software does this by changing the main mixer settings, rather than by adding a software attenuator -- so if, for instance, you cough while on Skype, the software will back down your input level significantly, and take a minute or so of quiet to bring it back up (longer if you're talking).

It's possible other sound recording software may have similar "auto level" settings that you can watch for or disable, but I know for certain this is present in Skype.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible that Audacity or [Audio Recorder](https://launchpad.net/~audio-recorder) have a similar setting? I am not using any other recording software.

Comment: @orschiro I haven't seen that setting in Audacity, but can't say it isn't there.  I haven't used Audio Recorder.  It'd be something to check the menus for.

Comment: I will see if I can find something related in the settings. Thank you again!